# Setting custom process as Heroku web process type

Tags: heroku, process, procfile, dyno

I have a git repository with two applications. One backend API, the other client-side application.

In my root Procfile, I have this:

```
api: cd apps/api && mix phx.server
clientside: cd apps/clientside && mix phx.server
```

However Heroku complains that there is no web process type.

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"
```

---

How can I tell Heroku to use a custom process in my procfile as the `web` process?

Comment: Set web dynos to 1 with `heroku ps:scale web=1` and tell me what error you get after trying to run the webapp.

Comment: I can't do that because the web process for Phoenix runs `mix phx.server` at the root folder of my umbrella, running both of my application on the same Heroku app. I need to specifically run my `api` or `clientside` process to only run one app.

Comment: try `api: mix apps/api/phx.server` and `clientside: mix apps/clientside/phx.server` in the procfile and run the command `heroku ps:scale api=1 clientside=1`

Comment: That's not the issue though, those dynos are on in their specific apps, that's fine. The problem is Heroku is not serving the router to these specific dynos, when they are the only dynos turned on in their specific heroku apps. I need a way to tell heroku "Use proc `clientside` to serve the heroku router."

Comment: Hm. What's the reason that you can't change `clientside` to `web`? I hope I'm not being too annoying, just trying to understand the problem.

Comment: I need to run different apps on different heroku apps. I can't specifiy two different apps with conditional logic in the `web` process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153713/discussion-between-illiteratecoder-and-sergio-tapia).